# Field entityManagerFactory in com.example.daoImpl.FileDaoImpl required a bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring-boot

i am getting the error Field entityManagerFactory in com.example.daoImpl.FileDaoImpl required a bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' that could not be found.

here is my main class

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com")
@EnableConfigurationProperties({ FileStorageProperties.class })
@ComponentScan({ "com" })
@EntityScan("com.example.model")

@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="com", entityManagerFactoryRef="emf")
public class DemoApplication {

    final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DemoApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        logger.info("Application is Started");
        new File(FileUploadController.uploadDirectory).mkdir();
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Here is my FileDaoImpl class

```
@Repository
public class FileDaoImpl implements FileDao{

    @Autowired
    EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    @Override
    public void encryptKey(EncryptKeys keys) {

        EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
      em.persist(keys);
    }
```

service class

```
@Service
public class FileStorageService {
 @Autowired
    FileDao filedao;
 public void encryptKey(EncryptKeys encryptKeys) {

         filedao.encryptKey(encryptKeys);
    }
```

what is wrong with this code.

Comment: You shoud uoload necessary codes in order someone can help

Comment: How `FileDao` is defined?

Comment: updated the source code

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

and my test case below, it works for me

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class TestRepo {

 @PersistenceContext
 private EntityManager entityManager;

 public void testPersist(){
    User user = new User();
    user.setUsername("persistTest");
    user.setPassword("testPwd");
    user.setRole("testRole");
    user.setUserId("testId");
    entityManager.persist(user);
 }
}
```

Comment: i mean use this annotation to replace the EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

Answer (score 0):

```
 @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="com", entityManagerFactoryRef="emf")
```

It trying to find bean "emf" for use it as entityManagerFactoryRef, i don't know mb you declare this bean somewhere else, but if not, do it

```
@Bean(name = "emf")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder, @Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = builder
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .packages("com")
            .persistenceUnit("someNameForUnit")
            .build();

   /* HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
    properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", hbm2ddl);
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", hibernateDialog);
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", showSql);
    properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", formatSql);
    em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties); */ this can set some property of jpa 
    return em;
}
```

But i think best solution let spring boot do this job as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Please make changes as following and try

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com")
@EnableConfigurationProperties({ FileStorageProperties.class })
//@ComponentScan({ "com" }) not needed since SpringBootApplication will fulfill this
@EntityScan("com.example.model")

@EnableJpaRepositories("com") // allow spring-boot-starter-data-jpa to do the needful
public class DemoApplication {

    final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DemoApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        logger.info("Application is Started");
        new File(FileUploadController.uploadDirectory).mkdir();
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```